# $scope.$apply not working due to callback

Tags: angularjs, callback

I am using ng-if in the frontend like this :

`div class="flex-row flex-space-around image-preview-panel" ng-if="files"
/* Some Code */
div`

This is not working as expected because $scope is not updating at the time of function call due to call of this function :

```
angular.module("mainController", [])

.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, $state) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.files = [];

    vm.showThumbnails = function() {
        for(var i=0;i<event.target.files.length;i++) {
            (function(i, file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        $scope.files[$scope.files.length] = file;
                    })
                }
            })(i, event.target.files[i]);
        }
    }
})
```

Any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry but are you sure about this line? .. that not givin you error? .. $scope.files[$scope.files.length] = file; .. how $scope.files can have a lentgh if it is a empty array?

Comment: Yes, its perfectly fine. As I already declared it as an array, its intial size is 0.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is being read successfully? If the FileReader gets an error it may not be calling the `onload` callback.

Comment: Yes its reading it succesfully. 
console.log(file) gives the desired output.
Only issues is that I am not able to have updated $scope.files for the frontend part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that `$scope.files` is initialised to an array so `ng-if="files"` is always true (in javascript an empty array is truthy). The condition should probably be `ng-if="files.length > 0"`

Comment: ng-if="files.length > 0" works.
If its 'true', why it was not visible the whole time and just worked when I updated the condition?

Comment: yes, I wondered that as well. It may depend on what you have in the `/* some code */`. Perhaps it drew once when `files` is empty but doesn't redraw when you add files because the expression in `ng-if` hadn't changed so there was no need to look at it again. But if you had something in the block that depended on the content of `files` that should redraw anyway.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable thing.
Thanks.